# Entity Framework Core unable to seed data within the DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have seen countless guides showing that seeding can be done in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`, but when I do it I get an error:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Example
```

results in:

> An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being created.

The only difference between my implementation and the ones I have read in docs and guides is that their `OnModelCreating` exclusively has the seeding methods enclosed in the scope of the method, whereas my implementation also defines primary keys and relationships between models. The relationship between my models work fine.

```
public class LogbookDbContext : DbContext
{
    public LogbookDbContext(DbContextOptions<LogbookDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Jump> Jumps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skydiver> Skydivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Airfield> Airfields { get; set; }

    protected EntityTypeBuilder<Skydiver> _skydiver;
    protected EntityTypeBuilder<Jump> _jump;
    protected EntityTypeBuilder<Flight> _flight;
    protected EntityTypeBuilder<Airfield> _airfield;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _skydiver = modelBuilder.Entity<Skydiver>();
        _jump = modelBuilder.Entity<Jump>();
        _flight = modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>();
        _airfield = modelBuilder.Entity<Airfield>();

        _skydiver.HasKey(x => x.PK_Skydiver_ID);
        _jump.HasKey(x => x.PK_Jump_ID);
        _flight.HasKey(x => x.PK_Flight_ID);
        _airfield.HasKey(x => x.PK_Airfield_ID);

        _skydiver.HasMany(x => x.Jumps).WithOne(x => x.Skydiver)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FK_Skydiver_ID);

        _flight.HasMany(x => x.Jumps).WithOne(x => x.Flight)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FK_Flight_ID);

        _airfield.HasMany(x => x.Flights).WithOne(x => x.Airfield)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FK_Airfield_ID);

        // An airfield will have admins. Admins are Skydivers.
        _airfield.HasMany(x => x.Admins).WithOne(x => x.AdminOf)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FK_Airfield_ID);

        _jump.Property(x => x.JumpCategory).HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (JumpCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(JumpCategory), v)
        );

        // this.Seeding(); // migration works without seeding
    }
}
```

The problem does not go away if I copy the code of the seeding function into this scope directly into `OnModelCreating` if that thought came to mind.

The actual implementation is much longer than this. They're arrays of model instances, but for brevity I am only including the first of each array.

```
private void Seeding()
{
    _airfield.HasData(new Airfield[] {
        new Airfield {
            PK_Airfield_ID = 1,
            Uuid = Util.GenerateUUID<Airfield>(this),
            Name = "Anonymous british airfield",
            Open = true,
            Nation = "England",
            County = "Shropshire"
        }
    });

    _skydiver.HasData(new Skydiver[] 
    {
        new Skydiver {
            PK_Skydiver_ID = 1,
            Uuid = Util.GenerateUUID<Skydiver>(this),
            Forename = "John",
            Surname = "Doe",
            Age = 24
        },

    });

    _flight.HasData(new Flight[] {
        new Flight {
            PK_Flight_ID = 1,
            Uuid = Util.GenerateUUID<Flight>(this),
            FK_Airfield_ID = 1,
            FlightStage = FlightStage.LANDED,
            ScheduledTakeoff = DateTime.Today.AddHours(13).AddMinutes(30),
            ActualTakeoffTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(13).AddMinutes(38),
            LandingTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(14).AddMinutes(12),
        },
    });

    _jump.HasData(new Jump[] {
        new Jump {
            PK_Jump_ID = 1,
            Uuid = Util.GenerateUUID<Jump>(this),
            FK_Flight_ID = 1,
            FK_Skydiver_ID = 1,
            Altitude = 6_000,
            JumpCategory = JumpCategory.CAT_FF,
            Note = "John Doe's Mid Altitude Jump"
        }, 
    });
}
```

I will not be showing models. They can be inferred from the `Seed()` method and they won't be related to the problem because I can confirm they're formatted correctly. As you can see I am using Fluent API which is why it's important that I define the relationships between the models in the `DbContext`.

Comment: You should avoid performing operations that require access to the database context or the database itself within OnModelCreating. Instead, consider performing your seeding operations outside of the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: The problem is **not** that *"my implementation also defines primary keys and relationships between models"*. This is the **primary** purpose of `OnModelCreating`, and model data seeding is the additional optional functionality. The actual problem is that you are using the model data seeding incorrectly. The error most likely is from `Util.GenerateUUID` passing `this` (`DbContext`) as argument, and I guess it is trying to use the `DbContext` for executing queries, which is not possible at that time. `.HasData` is seed **definition**, not seed operation. PKs and FKs must be **constants**.

Comment: Migration creates the database structure (tables and fields).  You cannot load data into the database until the struct is built.  If you are loading values into the database and another method to initialize the database, do not use the OnModelCreate.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without the code of the `Util.GenerateUUID` method.

Answer (score 0):

As some of you have pointed out in the comments. Some behaviour has not been shown in the original post. I can confirm the issue was within
`Util.GenerateUUID<T>(LogbookDbContext)`

This method was reading the database in order to confirm that generated UUIDs were unique. This caused the problem.